# jenkins: github plugin install: stuck at SCM API Plugin install

Tags: git, plugins, github, jenkins

I am trying to install GitHub plugin on a freshly installed Ubuntu 14.04 system with Jenking 1.605 running on it.

GitHub Plugin installation process is able to download "GitHub API Plugin" and "Git Client Plugin" but it is stuck now at "SCM API Plugin" at Pending state. I check the log file and I don't see any anomaly there.

INFO: Starting the installation of GitHub API Plugin on behalf of anonymous
Mar 18, 2015 5:35:05 AM hudson.model.UpdateCenter$UpdateCenterConfiguration download
INFO: Downloading GitHub API Plugin
Mar 18, 2015 5:35:06 AM hudson.model.UpdateCenter$DownloadJob run
INFO: Starting the installation of Git Client Plugin on behalf of anonymous
Mar 18, 2015 5:35:07 AM hudson.model.UpdateCenter$UpdateCenterConfiguration download
INFO: Downloading Git Client Plugin
Mar 18, 2015 5:35:11 AM hudson.model.UpdateCenter$DownloadJob run
INFO: Starting the installation of SCM API Plugin on behalf of anonymous

Your help is greatly appreciated!

Thanks in Advance
- J

Comment: Seems like a mirror server issue.. I moved my instances to a different data center and it solved the issue ..

Answer (score 2):

This is how I fixed it:

1. restart jenkins to stop the crashed installation (add /restart to the adress bar - i.e. http://localhost:8080/restart)
2. download the SCM API plugin separately (https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/SCM+API+Plugin) - get .hpi file
3. install manually from Jenkins (Manage Jenkins -> Manage Plugins -> Advanced -> Upload Plugin) You can do the same with the git and github plugins if you encounter additional problems.